# Gallery starting on text 2 instead of text 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery that user will click on the button, the gallery html will load inside div slideshow and each time user clicks on the text the next div holder will show.

The problem is, gallery is always starting on TEXT 2 instead of TEXT 1. Any ideas why?

my jquery:

```
$(document).on( "click", ".click", function() {
  var a = "<div class='holder active'>text 1 -> click to text 2</div><div class='holder'>text2 -> click to text 3</div><div class='holder'>text3 -> click to end</div>";

  $('#slideshow').html(a);
  slideSwitch();
});

$(document).on( "click", ".holder", function() {
    slideSwitch();
});

function slideSwitch() {
  var current = $('#slideshow .active');
  current.removeClass('active');
  if (current.next().length) {
      current.next().addClass('active');
  } else {
  alert("end");
    console.log('here');
      $('#slideshow').hide();
  }
}
```

My gallery always starting by the second post. any ideas how to solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/923ec6zL/

html

```
<span class=click>click to add html to slideshow div</span>


<div id=slideshow>


</div>
```

css

```
.holder{
  display:none;
}

.active{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: because first on is active and than you tell it to switch....

Comment: @epascarello can you give me an example how to solve this?

Comment: um, do not call slideSwitch

Comment: Check for instance http://jsfiddle.net/923ec6zL/1/

Comment: @epascarello oh thank you, so easy and I stay here trying for about 1 hour... thank you very much.

Comment: @user2314737 thank you too friend.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you start off calling current.next() to be active, rather than having the first click set current to active.  You should use some sort of variable to check if nothing is currently active, and if so, set the first one to active. (Right now the first is active by default, but it isn't added in until that current.next() is called)